# Can't get TextArea to scroll to bottom

Tags: javafx, kotlin

I am using Kotlin with JavaFX. In a TextArea which is programmatically appended, I want the scrollbar to always jump to the bottom when text is added.

To test this, I wrote this code:

```
taConsole.text = "Running " + pythonScriptPath

// retrieve output from python script
val bfr = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(p.inputStream))
val lines = bfr.readLines()
for (i in 1..10) {
    for (line in lines) {
        taConsole.appendText("\n" + line)
    }
}
```

Sadly, I cant get it to scroll to bottom. I already tried:

```
ta.selectEnd();
ta.deselect();

dataPane.setScrollTop(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

and

```
val caret = taConsole.selectPositionCaret(taConsole.length)
```

I inserted them after the:

```
appendText("\n" + line)
```

Comment: When I use `appendText`, it auto scrolls to the bottom of the `TextArea`.

Comment: Well, as you see, it doesn't for me. I don't know why, however...